# how to load more data in database through talend ETL

Tags: postgresql, talend

I have 6.5 GB data which consists 900000 rows in my Input table ****(tPostgresqlInput)** ,I am trying to load the same data into my output table(tPostgresqlOutput) , while running the job i am not getting any response from my input table, Is there Any solution to load the data? pls refer my attachment[image]

Comment: 6.5G / 900K := your average row size is > 7K. This doesn't look very sane to me.

Comment: Things start to get interesting when you have LOBs that are in the range of 700MB :) but talend can handle those as well with the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

You made need to develop a strategy to retrieve more manageable chunks of data, for example dividing up the data based on row IDs. That way, it does not take as much memory or time to retrieve the data .

You could also increase the Default memory limit for the job from 1 GB to a higher number .

If you job runs on the same network as your database server, that can also increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable Use Cursor on the Inputs advanced settings. The default 1k value is fine.
Also enable the batch size on the ouput which does similar.

By enabling this Talend will work with 1k records at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If this two tables are in the same DB you can try to use Talend ELT component
no push down you processing to the database. Take a look on following set of components:
https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide60EN/tELTPostgresqlInput
https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide60EN/tELTPostgresqlMap
https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide60EN/tELTPostgresqlOutput